AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.0.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally
Today I installed Apache2 on my Linux Mint 21.3 and was greeted with the following message when running sudo apachectl configtest, i.e. configuration test:

AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.0.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message

How to get it sorted?

See on Ask Ubuntu: Apache error "Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name"

Edit the following file with your favorite text editor as root, e.g.:
sudo vim /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

Go to the end of this file, and add this line:
ServerName 127.0.0.1

just before the VIM syntax specification:
# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet

Save the file, and run:
sudo apachectl configtest

it should now no longer say error AH00558, instead you should be greeted with Syntax OK.

There could be many more solutions, I guess this is more of a workaround - but maybe not. If you can do better than me, feel free to comment and answer, I will delete my answer in such a case.
